# List Comprehension Showing IndexError

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm creating a hangman game. I came up with an idea to replace underscores with a letter.  First the user inputs their guess (the letter "c" in this case). I search through a list containing the letters of the unknown word creating a list with the indices of each time there is a hit for that letter. Then I search through the list of underscores and replace all the underscores with the letter using the index list I created.  However, I'm getting an error:

> IndexError: list index out of range.

What am I doing wrong in the below code?

```
y = "cctcc"
to_modify = ["_", "_", "_","_", "_"]
replacements = list(y)

user_input = input()
indexes = [i for i, j in enumerate(replacements) if j == user_input]
print(indexes)
for index in indexes:
  to_modify[indexes[index]] = replacements[index]

print(to_modify)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-be2b07a156e5> in <module>()

     10 print(indexes)

     11 for index in indexes:

---> 12   to_modify[indexes[index]] = replacements[index]

     13 

     14 print(to_modify)


IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This section of the code is *already* looping over the indices:

```
for index in indexes:
    to_modify[indexes[index]] = replacements[index]
```

If `indexes` contains `[0,1,3,4]`, when `index` loops to `4` it's trying to access `indexes[4]` which is out of range, just use the indexes you're getting from the loop:

```
for index in indexes:
    to_modify[index] = replacements[index]
```